# Meteor's createUser running on client and server

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm fairly new to Meteor and trying to grasp its concepts. I have a client code below that triggers Meteor method to create new user:

```
Template["signup-team"].onRendered(function(){
    var validator = $('.signup-team-form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(event){
            var email = $('[name=email]').val();
            var password = $('[name=password]').val();
            Meteor.call('addNewUser', email, password, "team-captain", function(error, result) {
                if (error){
                    return alert(error.reason);
                }
                Router.go("complete-signup");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The method is defined to run on both client and server. When run on the server I want it to create user and add role to account. On the client side I want to sign user in.

```
Meteor.methods({
    addNewUser: function(email, password, role) {
        check(email, String);
        check(password, String);

        if(Meteor.isClient){
            Accounts.createUser({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                profile: {
                    completed: false
                }
            }, function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error); // Output error if registration fails
                } else {
                    console.log(Meteor.userId());
                }
            });
        } else {
            var id = Accounts.createUser({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                profile: {
                    completed: false
                }
            });
            console.log(id);
            Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, role);            
        }
    }
});
```

The server part runs fine and new user is created but on client side I get error `Error: No result from call to createUser` and user isn't signed in automatically.

I assume the problem is I dont need to run `createUser` on the client and use `Meteor.loginWithPassword` instead but I would really like to know the theory behind this. Thanks

Comment: You most likely don't want the client to tell you which roles to add to the user. A better approach would be to use [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser).

Comment: Yes, valid point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this.  You are rewriting core code and creating security issues needlessly.

Instead of using your `addNewUser` method, just call [`Accounts.createUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) on the client.  Have a [`onCreateUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) callback handle adding the role.

In your code, you are sending the users password to the server in plaintext.  When you call [`Accounts.createUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser), the [password is hashed](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L124) before being sent to the server.  It also takes care of logging in the new user for you.

One gotcha with adding the role though, you will not be able to use `Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, role)` in the `onCreateUser` callback, as the user object has not yet been added to the database, and does not have an `_id`.  However you can directly add the role to the proposed user object like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.roles = ['team-captain']  
  return user;
})
```

Then again, maybe you don't want all users to be team captains!

Comment: Thanks @JeremyK, sending password is indeed a bad idea. I assume Accounts.onCreateUser can be called on server only. How can I pass a role I need to set? (No, not all users suppose to be captainsJ)

Comment: Ok, I have attached roles to user.profile to read them on the server and then delete from object.